# Can't get image data when using WordPRess Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to upload image and crop that image and then get the image using following script:

https://github.com/trigo-at/slim-image-cropper-test

**Without WordPress I am using this HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Slim Image Cropper Test</title>
        <link href="slim/slim.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <body>
        <form action="" class="form" method="POST" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="frame">
                <input type="file" id="myCropper"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="register_btn" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="slim/slim.kickstart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**and the Ajax Script is**

```
$("#form").submit(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data    =  new FormData($('#form')[0]);                     
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'test.php',
        data : data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,               
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,     
        success: function( result ) {
            console.log( result );
        }
    });
});
```

**Now, on the test.php page I can get the image array data**

```
<?php 
require_once( 'server/slim.php' );

$imgs = Slim::getImages();
print_r( $imgs );
```

**NOW, for this WordPRess Ajax call it's not getting the image data :(**

**WordPress Ajax Call**

```
$("#form").submit(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var register_type   = '' ;
        register_type   = $(this).data('register-type');
    var data    =  new FormData($('#form')[0]);    
        data.append("action", "register_action");
        data.append("register_type", register_type);                    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : settings.ajaxurl,
        data : data,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,               
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,     
        success: function( result ) {
            console.log( result );
        }
    });
});
```

**WordPress HTML form part:**

```
<form action="" class="form" method="POST" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group">     
          <div class="frame">
               <input type="file" id="myCropper"/>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">                      
          <div id="form_result"></div>
          <?php wp_nonce_field( 'register_action' ); ?>                             
          <input type="submit" name="submit" data-register-type="<?php echo hashMe('ccroipr_register_p', 'e'); ?>"  id="register_btn" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">
     </div>
</form>
```

**WordPress PHP Part ( get nothign :():**

```
echo '<pre>';
    $imgs = Slim::getImages();
    print_r( $imgs );
 echo '</pre>';

**PHP output:** 

<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [input] => 
            [output] => 
            [actions] => 
            [meta] => 
        )

)
</pre>
```

But without WordPress, I can get the image array data.

**Can someone tell me what's going wrong here please?**

Comment: You've set `dataType: 'json'` so jQuery will attempt to parse the result as JSON but `print_r($imgs);` will definitely not produce JSON

Comment: So shall I must use `html` as `dataType` ?